# Ubuntu General Instability / crash triggers Windows 8.1 startup repair

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, kernel, crash

Let me begin with my usual statement that I only ask questions on StackExchange sites when I can't find anything on Google, and that my question-asking skills are rusty, so forgive me blah blah blah...

**So**, this question is a two-parter. I would normally separate these into two separate questions, but they are both dealing with the same issues, more or less, so I feel this is most appropriate.

First part: General instability. Or, "**Why is my system so unstable?**"

It seems like every time I leave this particular machine/system on for extended periods of time (see details at bottom), it will randomly kernel panic, crash, or just freeze completely. The longest uptime I've recorded is about 18 hours. This is probably the most pathetically unstable Linux distro (or machine?) I've ever run. Even Windows Vista would run for at least 20 hours (albeit with a random 10-20 minute lock-up about 5 hours in). It's like watching an old man with acute laryngitis during a particularly extreme coughing fit. In other words, it's disturbing. It's not like I run a bunch of heavy software, either. The most cpu-intensive app I use is Firefox, and even then, I make a point to use wget instead of firefox's downloader, and stream youtube videos via vlc as opposed to dealing with Flash's lagginess (Flash actually runs pretty decently on this machine. So this is more of an old habit).

The last system I ran (Linux Mint 15 32-bit on a dell inspiron laptop) could go on for months before some strange thing happened forcing me to reboot, like the sound daemon crashing and refusing to start back up properly, or getting logged out and having the system unable to accept my password, or the, then-rare, "not syncing" kernel panic (which is all-too-common for me now). The longest uptime I had on that one was an impressive 4 months and 3 days before the motherboard finally fried itself during a power surge and I had to buy this one (as well as a surge protector / battery backup to prevent that from happening again).

So that's the situation with the general instability. Now let's move on to the second part.

Part 2: the strange experience I had today. Or, "**Why did a Ubuntu crash trigger Windows 8.1 startup repair?**"

I went to an appointment today. I was also in the middle of a huge file-organizing operation with my Music and Video libraries. So I decided to leave the computer on, against my better judgement (see part 1). When I got back, I found my appliances showing the telltale signs of a power outage. So I checked on my computer to see if the backup battery had done its job, and I was half-delighted to see the power light was on. But when I turned my monitors on, I was greeted by the Windows 8.1 startup repair. This...makes absolutely no sense. For one, I haven't known Ubuntu (or any flavor of Linux, for that matter) to automatically reboot, even in the event of a crash. For another, I wasn't even running Windows. And the last time I was, it was a perfectly clean shutdown. Why would Ubuntu crashing cause Windows to "need" a startup repair? As far as I know, there's no way that a system on a separate partition could affect the other partition if the other partition wasn't mounted.

I have been having some of the most perplexing problems with this setup, but this one just takes the cake.

I've never been sure which logs I should be copy/pasting, but here is some highly detailed information about the state of my system before the crash (not to imply the crash did any real damage...it didn't), in case somehow some specific combination of software is capable of destroying a system's stability:

```
Hardware:      
    Acer Aspire XC Tower 
    2 x Acer monitor
Other:
    Surge Protector/Backup Battery combo unit
    Ethernet Cable to connect to internet
    WiFi antenna. Forgot why I installed it.
Systems:
    Windows 8.1
    Ubuntu 14.04.1 (Kernel 3.13.0-40-generic)
Address size:
    Hardware:         64 bits
    Operating System: 64 bits
X version:
    X.Org X Server 1.15.1 
    2014-04-13 
    X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Environment: 
    i3 window manager 
    no desktop
    version 4.7.2 (2014-01-23, branch "tags/4.7.2")
Recently used software and their versions: 
    firefox   (v33.0), 
    xterm     (v297), 
    bash      (v4.3.11(1)-release)
    htop      (v1.0.2), 
    alsamixer (v1.0.27.2), 
    vim       (v7.4), 
    mc        (v4.8.11), 
    cmus      (v2.5.0)
```

I'll add additional information/logs here upon request, and thank you very much for taking the time to read this.

**Update**: After nearly a year of dealing with this, I've been slowly pinpointing the cause of this problem. Turns out, it's not Ubuntu. It *can't* be Ubuntu. It just *looks* like it is because my use of the Windows partition pales dramatically in comparison to my use of the Ubuntu partition. I'm sure that if I used Windows for long enough, it, too, would lock up eventually.

It's the CPU. I figured this out a few months ago when I started running scripts during my sessions to log what's going on, as well as setting up my magic key for being able to perform the beloved `SysRQ + REISUB` combo. Not only did all logs, including those dumped by the kernel, end abruptly in the event of a freeze, but the kernel wouldn't respond to any magic keys. Temperature is normal. Sound will loop like an N64 game when it freezes. Actually, the freeze is very similar to an NES/SNES/N64 freeze. Everything is normal, as if no freeze ever occurred, yet everything just abruptly stops in time. In short, somehow, [the CPU is getting locked up](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2228805.html).

So since the problem is the hardware and not Ubuntu, I'm taking the first half of this is question over to [superuser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76731/).

Comment: please make your answer small and precise, other wise you wont get many answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I may have skimmed through your question but, rule of thumb, Linux and Windows should stick to their own hard drives. They'll always try to take priority over each other, even on separate partitions.

*Edit: I would try to not use any Windows repair tool while both OS's are partitioned on the drive. Gparted shouldn't mess anything up but, tools like it can confuse Windows, especially on boot up.

Comment: I didn't run it. I just shut down and booted back into Linux. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: However, the question is about instability, which you didn't quite answer. It's not as if windows being on the same drive is causing Linux to panic...is it?

Comment: It's most likely another problem, unless you have Windows somehow probing your Linux partition, I don't see that happening.